# How to handle with no Internet and lost connection in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an application that needs to connect to the Internet to perform some actions but when no Internet available it will crash. I read that I need to use try catch bracket in case no Internet. I tried to use it as you can see in AsyncTask but it doesn't work. I don't know why. The app crashes. How to deal with try catch where to put it in my code?

One more thing what about if the app lost Internet connection while process is going on. How supposed I to deal with this thing so my app doesn't crash. Thank you very much.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.home);
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mybookslistview);

  new connectToServer().execute();
}


class connectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
  CustomListViewAdapter adapter;
  HttpResponse response;
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      ids_list.clear();
      names_list.clear();
      writers_list.clear();

      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      list.add(new BasicNameValuePair(word, connectionPurpose));
      try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list, HTTP.UTF_8));
        response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        String tempVar = "";
        while((tempVar = br.readLine()) != null){
          sb.append(tempVar);
        }
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      //Get data from stringbuffer and put it in array list
      if(!sb.toString().trim().contentEquals("null")){
        content_array = sb.toString().split(",");
        for(int s = 0; s < content_array.length; s++){
          if(content_array[s].contains("-")){
            String temp[] = content_array[s].split("-");
            ids_list.add(temp[0].trim());
            names_list.add(temp[1].trim());
            writers_list.add(temp[2].trim());
          }
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

      if(!mWifi.isConnected()){
        adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
        adb.setMessage("لا يوجد إنترنت. قم بتفعيل الإنترنت ثم حاول مرة أخرى.");
        adb.setPositiveButton("حاول مجددا", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            new connectToServer().execute();
            }
            });
        adb.setNegativeButton("إغلاق التطبيق", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            }
            });
        //It shows dialog if no connection
        adb.create().show();
      }else{
        list = new ArrayList<Home.ListViewItem>();
        for(x = 0; x < ids_list.size(); x++){
          list.add(new ListViewItem(){{bookName = names_list.get(x); writerName = writers_list.get(x);}});
        }
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(Home.this, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(sb.toString().trim().contentEquals("null")){
          Toast.makeText(Home.this, "لا توجد نتائج.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
```

**This is my logcat:**

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "globalmall.ca": No address associated with hostname
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at readit.Mansour.inc.Home$connectToServer.doInBackground(Home.java:106)
    at readit.Mansour.inc.Home$connectToServer.doInBackground(Home.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
    ... 18 more
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    ... 21 more
threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e582a0)
```

Comment: So, based on the logcat, can you indicate what line in your source is line #106?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Appending StringBuffer.    while((tempVar = br.readLine()) != null){
      sb.append(tempVar);}

Comment: UnknownHostException is not catched up.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán What does that mean?

Comment: @MansourFahad If you don't have Internet connection, host name cannot be resolved, so `UnknownHostException` will be thrown

Comment: @RafiKamal Thank you for you comment. What should I do to skip that line if no Internet?

Comment: catch the `UnknownHostException` in the try-catch block, then you can show the user a message saying that Internet connection is not available

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either create `method` or some class may be where you can instantiate method as `static`.

Here is a method named `isConnectedToInternet()` which checks whether internet is connected or not. Return boolean on the basis of connection back to the calling function.

Snippet:

```
 public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

You can decide on the basis of return value of `isConnectedToInternet()` whether to execute `AysncTask` or Throw some pop up. Here i've been added user to brought in his `Data Settings`.

Something like these:

```
  if(isConnectedToInternet())
   {
      // Run AsyncTask
    }
   else
   {
      // Here I've been added intent to open up data settings
   Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MAIN);
   ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
   intent.setComponent(cName); 
    }
```

---

As you mentioned what if you looses connection in between. You can check the status code as per the reponse of httpclient and pop up relevant information to user.
You can integrate these snippet under `AysncTask`.

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response = null;
  response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
  int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: That's seems a good solution but what about if lost connection?

Comment: @MansourFahad: I've added snippet against your OP in comment.

Comment: For connection lose use BroadcastReceiver with this filter : android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Comment: i am trying the same solution but since it will be in the repository i think the best solution is to throw a custom exception which by handling it in the viewmodel will show error message or whatever action needed when connection lost

Answer (score 4):

```
public class CheckNetClass {

    public static Boolean checknetwork(Context mContext) {

        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                           .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) {
            // here is the roaming option, you can change it if you want to
            // disable internet while roaming, just return false
            return true;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Use this class to check internet availability like:

```
if (CheckNetClass.checknetwork(getApplicationContext())) 
{
new GetCounterTask().execute();
} 
else
{   
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry,no internet connectivty",1).show();   
}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. You have in your stack trace these lines:

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
readit.Mansour.inc.Home$connectToServer.doInBackground(Home.java:106)
```

Which mean that the offending line is

```
response = client.execute(post);
```

Which is different from the line that you mentioned. Verify the stack trace & the line that it mentions. Also, see that if you fix it by catching `Exception`. If you don't, then  you have a bigger problem, because `UnknownHostException` is a subclass of `IOException`, which you already catch.